# What is the purpose behind multiple addressing modes in a processor

Tags: computer-architecture

Processors usually have multiple addressing modes. All processors do not have the same exact same list of addressing modes.

1. When exactly was idea of different addressing modes conceived?
2. Why do we need so many different addressing modes?
3. Why are the addressing modes transparents when programming in high level languages?

Answer (score 2):

Address modes at the ISA level (a different topic from what [Jack Creasey is talking about](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/414655/11683)) are designed to make the processor more efficient for typical applications. If a common operation can be done with fewer instructions, it saves both memory and time.

A programmer typically uses data in a number of different ways.

- Sometimes, the same value is always used for a given operation, which leads to the "immediate" mode of addressing, in which the data is actually part of the instruction.
- Sometimes a programmer wants to use a global variable, which leads to the "direct" mode of addressing, in which the data memory address is part of the instruction.
- Sometimes a programmer wants to use a variable that is local to a given function, and wants to be able to use that function recursively. This leads to an addressing mode in which an offset relative to the stack pointer is part of the instruction.
- Sometimes a programmer wants to keep data in an array, in which case, both the base address of the array and an index into the array need to be specified. This leads to an indexed mode of addressing, in which both values are typically pulled from registers (the register names are part of the instruction).
- Speaking of arrays, stacks (LIFO) and buffers (FIFO) are very common in many types of programming, which leads to autoincrement and autodecrement addressing modes.
- More complicated data structures (lists, trees, etc.) require pointers and references, which lead to various levels of indirection (i.e., an address of an address) in addressing modes, which can be combined in various ways with all of the previous modes.

And so forth and so on.

As you say, different processors have different sets of addressing modes, which makes some of them not suitable (or at least less optimal) for certain types of problems.

> 1. When exactly was idea of different addressing modes conceived?

Pretty much from day 1. Computer architects realized early on that these modes of data access would be important.

> 2. Why do we need so many different addressing modes?

See the list above.

> 3. Why are the addressing modes transparents when programming in high level languages?

These concepts are common to both assembly-language and high-level language programming, so it is relatively straightforward for a compiler to pick the correct mode.

Comment: Does the programmer need to be aware of which addressing mode to use when writing assembly or will the processor or the assembler automatically figure it out?

Comment: @quantum231: Yes, the programmer needs to select the addressing mode in assembly language, just like he has to use the correct syntax (to distinguish between literals, globals, locals, arrays, etc.) in any HLL.

Comment: I thought that based on the instruction we are using and its location, the addressing mode shall become clear. I guess the only way to fully understand this is to use it by writing assembly program.

Answer (score 2):

- "When exactly was idea of different addressing modes conceived?"

Such ideas are not conceived as such, you start with one addressing mode, then add another (in the same computer design, or in a new computer) because it seemed like a good idea at that time. Read up on designs of the oldest computers. In most cases their architecture (including addressing modes) was dictated by the properties of the available hardware (at that time). That is one big reason why CPU and instruction set evolved over time: the available hardware evolved.

- Why do we need so many different addressing modes?

Mostly to make efficient use of the (scarce) bits in instructions. Also (historically) to make the most of the limited number of transistors in a chip.

- Why are the addressing modes transparents when programming in high level languages?

Because a high level language is *high level* and *target-independent*. In recent CPU designs things work backwards: the CPUs have the addressing modes that can be used (by compilers) to implement the high-level languages in the most effective way. That is how different CPU design options are evaluated. (read Hennesey & Patterson)

Answer (score 1):

Early processors only had direct memory addressing (called linear or logical addressed memory) and so could address only small amounts of RAM depending on the memory address bus width of the cpu.

As memory needs increased there was a pressing need to increase the amount of memory that could be addressed, and various schemes were developed:

1. Page mapped memory which used I/O ports to select different 'pages' (typically 1k words) of memory that could be mapped into the linear address space.
2. Increases to the linear memory address bus size from 16 - 32 -48 - 64 bits of direct address space.
3. Mapped address space where the cpu linear address bus is isolated (and now called a virtual address space) from the physical address bus by an address translation unit.

3 is where most advanced processors are today, with 32 or 64 bit processor linear or vitual address space and a physical address space to suite the memory size. The LA (logical address) is mapped through page tables that describe the mapping from LA to PA (Physical address) memory which can now extend to Terabytes mapped memory into a much smaller linear/logical address space.

Read [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-memory-is-accessed) for more coverage.

Answer (score 1):

three answers: relative addressing allows easy swapping (virtual memory) of program code; when swapping a page back in, the base register for that page is given the correct value, and all the jumps and data fetches use that base address.  I first noticed this ability in the Motorola MC6809.

: Read this link about Maurice Wilkes

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Wilkes

Another "addressing" mode, on the Data General Nova 1200, was called the "decrement-and-skip-if-zero" instruction, useful for stepping thru arrays of known length or thru character strings of known length.

3: Indexed-register addressing first came to my attention as I examined the PDP11 instructions; that mode allowed a "register" to be set to the starting address of an array, and used in stepping thru the array (or the string, or interrupt vectors, etc.). This allows arrays to become dynamic, re-sizable, and to be re-located anywhere in main memory; no need to keep code and data in one monolithic contiguous region.

These historical references are by no means the first use of various addressing modes; I suspect the Brits were using all of these in the 1950s. You might examine the Whirlwind instruction set, of the 1950, for that machine's flexibility. Or the SAGE machine.

=================

In the 1960s just about every aerospace company (such as Singer Librascope (yes, the sewing machine company)) produced its own "minicomputers" for use in autonomous-guided robotic aircraft used for automatic photographing of terrain is warzones.

I recall MIT? producing a submarine-rated computer, sized to be lowered thru a hatch of small diameter, for on-patrol evaluation of hydrophone sensor data, using moderate precision math to detect other subs; this was in the late 1950s, as soon as transistors became available.